# Groovy: find the cheapest price by a specific tag in an array list

Tags: groovy

Not sure how to handle this efficently. I have an array list that looks like this:

```
 [[name:BOB, cost:225.99, ticket:ECONOMY, stops:1], [name:JIM, cost:331.99, ticket:PREMIUM, stops:0], [name:SAL, cost:331.99, ticket:ECONOMY, stops:0], [name:PETE, cost:456.99, ticket:PREMIUM, stops:0]]
```

That's just an example.

What I want out of this is this, a data structure (doesn't matter what kind, string is fine, that contains:

- 1 entry with 0 stops, ticket type ECONOMY, that has the cheapest cost
- 1 entry with more than 0 stops, ticket type ECONOMY, that has the cheapest cost
- 1 entry with 0 stops, ticket type PREMIUM, that has the cheapest cost
- 1 entry with more than 0 stops , ticket type PREMIUM that has the cheapest cost

Not all of those categories may have data in the array list, if it doesn't fine, just ignore it.

What's the easiest way to go about this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `findAll()` and `min()` collection functions. The first  one will let you filter the list of all entries using a predicate, the second one will let you get one entry with smallest value of a specific field. Consider following example:

```
def data = [
  [name: 'BOB', cost: 225.99, ticket: 'ECONOMY', stops: 1],
  [name: 'JIM', cost: 331.99, ticket: 'PREMIUM', stops: 0],
  [name: 'SAL', cost: 331.99, ticket: 'ECONOMY', stops: 0],
  [name: 'PETE', cost: 456.99, ticket: 'PREMIUM', stops: 0]
]

// 1 entry with 0 stops, ticket type PREMIUM, that has the cheapest cost
def result = data.findAll { it.stops == 0 && it.ticket == 'PREMIUM' }.min { it.cost }

println result.inspect()
```

Output:

```
['name':'JIM', 'cost':331.99, 'ticket':'PREMIUM', 'stops':0]
```

This example shows how you can use `findAll()` and `min()` to achieve your goal:

- `findAll { it.stops == 0 && it.ticket == 'PREMIUM' }` reduces the list of all entries to ones that have 0 stops and ticket type PREMIUM
- `min { it.cost }` returns single entry from filtered list with the smallest `cost` value.

You can simply apply the same strategy to extract all remaining information and store it in any structure you like.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's causing an error. groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: it for class: DUMMY     ???

Comment: Got it! Needs quotes around the 0!